# Yii - Unexpected logout link in the view

Tags: yii

Welcome.

I have a strange situation because my Yii framework itself generates links for logged off and put it in the body of view of each element (span, div, li and other)
By this problem, on every click in the body of the view I get logged off

To generate view i used $this->render();

In result DOM look like this:

```
<section class="top-line">
    <div class="right">
         <a href="/workflow/?r=user/logout"> </a>
    </div>
    <a href="/workflow/?r=user/logout"> </a>
</section>
<a href="/workflow/?r=user/logout">
  <div class="main-box">...</div>
</a>

<footer>
<a href="/workflow/?r=user/logout"> </a>
<div class="container">..</div>
</footer>
```

@DarkMukke  Include layouts/main.php:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="language" content="en" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- blueprint CSS framework -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo baseUrl(); ?>/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo baseUrl(); ?>/css/print.css" media="print" />
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo baseUrl(); ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo baseUrl(); ?>/css/form.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo baseUrl(); ?>/css/blue/style.css" />

    <?php
    $cs = cs();
    $cssCoreUrl = $cs->getCoreScriptUrl();
    $cs->registerCssFile($cssCoreUrl . '/jui1.9.2/css/base/jquery-ui.css');
    $cs->registerCoreScript('jquery');
    $cs->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');
    $cs->registerCoreScript('cookie');
    $cs->registerScriptFile('js/block.js');
    $cs->registerScriptFile('js/global.js');
    $cs->registerScriptFile('css/blue/style.js');
    ?>

    <title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
</head>
<body>

    <header class="top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>" ><?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name); ?></a></h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <?php $this->widget('Menu'); ?>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="top-line">
        <div class="container">
            <?php if (isset($this->breadcrumbs)): ?>
                <div class="left">
                    <?php
                    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs', array(
                        'links' => $this->breadcrumbs,
                    ));
                    ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest == false): ?>
                <div class="right">
                    <a href="<?php echo url('/user/logout'); ?>"><?php echo t('Logout') . ' (' . Yii::app()->user->name . ')'; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="main-box">
         <div class="container clear">
                <div class="clear cenetr">
                    <?php
                    foreach (Yii::app()->user->getFlashes() as $key => $message) {
                        echo '<div class="flash-' . $key . '">' . $message . " <span class=\"close-flush-btn\"></span></div>\n";
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="fleft"><?php echo Yii::app()->params['copyrightInfo']; ?></div>
                <div class="fright"><?php echo Yii::powered(); ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Has anyone had this problem? Which may result from such conduct.

[Solved] My stupid mistake. Do not shut a tag in logout link and body react on every click. What a shame .. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: can you post your /protected/views/layout/main.php ?

Comment: And what are those 'block.js' and 'global.js' scripts ? I think that the logout links are added on client side (by JavaScript), not on server side (by Yii).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have you main-box inside your  tag

use this as last 3 lines there, otherwise every click on main-box willt rigger the  element

```
<a href="/workflow/?r=user/logout"> </a>
<div class="main-box">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry it was an unfortunate piece of code. Of course <a> tag is closed. Just edited.


The thing is that all these loogout links are added by Yii.

Answer (score 0):

Content you want available for users not logged in, use

```
if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
echo 'your content';
}
```

Content for users logged in

```
if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
echo 'your content';
}
```

Let me now if that works. If it doesn't, you have something wrong in your UserIdentity class

Comment: No difference, I put the view in the clause for registered users  and everything display  but the logout links have been. Wrog Identy Class is probably a good clue .. I will check

Comment: what's the output for var_dump(Yii::app()->user) in both cases? (when you are logged in and when you are not)

Comment: Exactly the same thing, that's weird

Comment: Can i see your UserIdentity class? Are you sure you are logged in the user?